# python decorating instance method with parameter changes

Tags: python, decorator

I'm trying to make a decorator which can be used for any methods or functions, and I want to modify the arguments passed to the func at the same time.
Here's an example:

```
import math

def chunk(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

def divide_and_run(func):
    def wrapper(self, entries, *args, **kwargs):
        output = []
        for c in chunk(entries, 3):
            output.append(func(self, c, *args, **kwargs))
        return output
    return wrapper

class Dummy:
    @divide_and_run
    def multiply_all(self, mylist):
        return math.prod(mylist)

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
d = Dummy()

print(d.multiply_all(a))
```

The decorator `divide_and_run` divides `mylist`, runs `func` on each `chunk`, and returns the list of outputs. But this one cannot be used for a free function (no self argument)

I want two things:

1. Modify the argument passed to func (`mylist` -> `chunk`)
2. Make this decorator usable regardless of the method or function type (e.g., instance method or free function)

What's the best practice?
Is decorator a good use when I modify the arguments?

Answer (score 2):

The reason that it's hard to write a decorator that works on both top-level functions and on methods is that you can't tell which argument you want to be modifying will be. In your example, you always modify the `entries` argument to `wrapper`, which is the second argument. But if you were running on a top-level function, there would be no `self` argument, so the argument you'd want to change would be the first one.

One way to solve this is to write a callable descriptor type, rather than making your decorator return a function (which is a descriptor with method-binding behavior). This way you can react differently if you're called normally than if you're called as a method.

Here's a simple implementation that handles methods by creating a new instance on a bound method if it gets looked up as a method.

```
class divide_and_run:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, entries, *args, **kwargs):  # non-method calls
        return [self.func(c, *args, **kwargs) for c in chunk(entries, 3)]

    def __get__(self, obj, obj_type):    # handles method lookups on an instance
        return divide_and_run(self.func.__get__(obj, obj_type))
```

This implementation has one flaw, which is that it doesn't support unbound method lookups on a class (e.g. `Dummy.multiply_all(d, a)`). That is not impossible to solve, you just need to check that `obj` is not `None` in `__get__` and do something appropriate if it is. But the "something appropriate" is a bit fiddly, and I decided it would distract from the current code which is very concise.

Answer (score 1):

The [types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html) module provides a way to distinguish between method and function.

```
import types

# ...

def divide_and_run(func):
    if isinstance(func, types.MethodType):
        def wrapper(self, entries, *args, **kwargs):
            output = []
            for c in chunk(entries, 3):
                output.append(func(self, c, *args, **kwargs))
            return output
    elif isinstance(func, types.FunctionType):
        def wrapper(entries, *args, **kwargs):
            output = []
            for c in chunk(entries, 3):
                output.append(func(c, *args, **kwargs))
            return output
    return wrapper
```

---

A hacky and less robust way could be

```
if func.__code__.co_varnames[0] == 'self': # <- hardcoded!
   ...
else:
   ...
```

The disadvantage is that when declaring the instance method the reference to the object must be done with `self` identifier

---

**EDIT**

There are many many possible ways to implement the "same" decorator. Each is tight together with a specific signature hence on the way you want to call it. I just tried to be more faithful to the requirements and I discuss only two cases.

Summary: `divide_and_run_DIY` always works;  check **remark 3.** for the reason that `divide_and_run_SS` is not universal

Remarks:

0. notation: `SS` is used for Syntactic Sugar and `DIY` for Do It Yourself (without the *@*)
1. classification of callables. It is quite an hard task and I haven't found a solution yet. It will play an important role for the *@-decoration*.
   The following pairs of methods are equivalents `types.MethodType` and `inspect.ismethod`, `types.FunctionType` and `inspect.isfunction`. Only useful for the `DIY` solution.
2. syntactic sugar decoration. I realize that *@decoration* change the type of the callable, *kind of automatic casting*, which then make its classification harder for the purpose of the question (see previous remark). Here an example:

2A: The *@-decoration* cast the **decorated function** from an instance method to a function:

```
class Dummy:
    @divide_and_run_SS
    def multiply_all(self, mylist): return math.prod(mylist)

ss = Dummy().multiply_all
print(ss.__closure__[0].cell_contents)
#<function Dummy.multiply_all at 0x7f3ed8be25e0>
```

2B: The *DIY-decoration* of the **decorated function** doesn't change its type:

```
class Dummy:
    def multiply_all(self, mylist): return math.prod(mylist)

diy = divide_and_run_SS(Dummy().multiply_all)
print(print(diy.__closure__[0].cell_contents))
#<bound method Dummy.multiply_all of <__main__.Dummy object at 0x7f3ed8c4ce80>>
```

Notice that printing `func.__closure__[0].cell_contents` has the same effect as adding to the source code a `print(func)` statement.

3. two possible answers are presented. `divide_and_run_DIY` is stable for DIY-decoration (+SS-decoration of function only!). Instead, the other, `divide_and_run_SS`, is not universal but needs to *ad-hoc* implementation each time. The causes are mentioned in the previous remarks.

About the issues with `divide_and_run_SS`:

```
def divide_and_run_SS(func):
    def wrapper(entries, *args, **kwargs):
        # do smt with func(..., *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class Dummy:
    @divide_and_run_SS
    def multiply_all(self, mylist):
        return math.prod(mylist)
```

From 2.A: *@-decoration* change type

`multiply_all: bound method` --`divide_and_run_SS`--> `multiply_all: function`

... and the problems arises:

- **such change of type pass the reference of the instance as a parameter** (the usual `self`) to the `wrapper`, in this case `args[0]` will be `self`
- the decorator is expected to work both with instance method and function but the *@-decoration* cast to function so how could the decorator distinguish them? No idea... here I presented an hardcoded solution. A speculative approach is already mentioned in the original answer (the hacky way and it is probably the best tmp-fix).

4. the post seems long but it's just few lines... I used verbose doc-strings in order to be checked with `doctest`. I found it very useful to deal with such problem
5. extension of the problem to **Part 2** has exactly the same issues.

---

**Header**

```
import math
import types
#import inspect #   in alternative to types
import doctest  #   check correctness of the code in the comments


def chunk(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]
```

**Part 2** *Make this decorator usable regardless of the method or function type (e.g., instance method or free function)*

DIY-Syntax: `divide_and_run_SS(func)(args_func)`

```
def divide_and_run_DIY(func):
    """DIY (Manual) decoration. It works for SS of functions BUT it fails with methods
    >>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    >>> print('DIY (Manual) decoration')
    DIY (Manual) decoration
    >>> def f(mylist): return math.prod(mylist)
    >>> divide_and_run_DIY(f)(a)
    [6, 120, 504, 10]
    >>> # <function f at 0x7f7e47977ee0>
    >>> class Dummy:
    ...     def multiply_all(self, mylist): return math.prod(mylist)
    >>> divide_and_run_DIY(Dummy().multiply_all)(a)
    [6, 120, 504, 10]
    >>> # <bound method Dummy.multiply_all of <__main__.Dummy object at 0x7f7e47939820>>
    >>> print('='*20)
    ====================
    >>> print('SS decoration')
    SS decoration
    >>> print('Test with a function')
    Test with a function
    >>> @divide_and_run_DIY
    ... def f(mylist): return math.prod(mylist)
    >>> f(a)
    [6, 120, 504, 10]
    >>> # <function f at 0x7f8877ab5670>
    >>> print('Test with a method')
    Test with a method
    >>> class Dummy:
    ...     @divide_and_run_DIY
    ...     def multiply_all(self, mylist): return math.prod(mylist)
    >>> Dummy().multiply_all(a)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    TypeError: object of type 'Dummy' has no len()
    >>> # <function Dummy.multiply_all at 0x7f8877ab5700>
    """
    if isinstance(func, types.MethodType):
        def wrapper(entries, *args, **kwargs):
            output = []
            for c in chunk(entries, 3):
                output.append(func(c, *args, **kwargs))
            return output
    elif isinstance(func, types.FunctionType):
        def wrapper(entries, *args, **kwargs):
            output = []
            for c in chunk(entries, 3):
                output.append(func(c, *args, **kwargs))
            return output
    return wrapper


def divide_and_run_SS(func):
    """syntactic sugar decoration. It works both DIY and SS decoration BUT it is not universal! Check the DANGER comments and remark 3.
    >>> print('Syntactic sugar decoration')
    Syntactic sugar decoration
    >>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    >>> print('instance method')
    instance method
    >>> class Dummy:
    ...     @divide_and_run_SS
    ...     def multiply_all(self, mylist): return math.prod(mylist)
    >>> Dummy().multiply_all(a)
    [6, 120, 504, 10]
    >>> # <function Dummy.multiply_all at 0x7f4c8b5a70d0> # DANGER: it is a function!!
    >>> print('function')
    function
    >>> @divide_and_run_SS
    ... def f(mylist): return math.prod(mylist)
    >>> f(a)
    [6, 120, 504, 10]
    >>> # <function f at 0x7f4c8b58dee0>
    >>> print('='*20)
    ====================
    >>> print('SS (Manual) decoration')
    SS (Manual) decoration
    >>> print('function')
    function
    >>> def f(mylist): return math.prod(mylist)
    >>> divide_and_run_SS(f)(a)
    [6, 120, 504, 10]
    >>> # <function f at 0x7f0725fd5670>
    >>> print('instance method')
    instance method
    >>> class Dummy:
    ...     def multiply_all(self, mylist): return math.prod(mylist)
    >>> divide_and_run_SS(Dummy().multiply_all)(a)
    [6, 120, 504, 10]
    >>> # <bound method Dummy.multiply_all of <__main__.Dummy object at 0x7f0726056f40>>
    """
    def wrapper(entries, *args, **kwargs):
        output = []
        # unnatural fix
        if len(args) > 0: # func <- "method" is a function due to @SS
            # reparametrization
            __self = entries     # <- DANGER
            __entries = args[0]  # <- DANGER
            for c in chunk(__entries, 3):
                output.append(func(__self, c, *args[1:], **kwargs))
        else: # func <- function
            for c in chunk(entries, 3):
                output.append(func(c, *args, **kwargs))
        return output
    return wrapper
```

Check output with

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # run doctest
    doctest.testmod()

    # print __doc__
    print(divide_and_run_SS.__name__)
    print('#' * len(divide_and_run_SS.__name__))
    print(divide_and_run_SS.__doc__.replace('\t', ''))

    print(divide_and_run_DIY.__name__)
    print('#' * len(divide_and_run_DIY.__name__))
    print(divide_and_run_DIY.__doc__.replace('\t', ''))
```

**Part 2** + **Part 1** *Modify the argument passed to func (mylist -> chunk)*

DIY-Syntax: `Dec(f1)(args_f1).divide_and_run_DIY(f2)(args_f2)`

```
class Dec:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *func_args, **func_kwargs):
        self.func_args, self.func_kwargs = func_args, func_kwargs
        return self

    def divide_and_run_DIY(self, f_target):
        """DIY (Manual) decoration. It works also for SS of functions BUT it fails with methods
        >>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        >>> print('DIY (Manual) decoration')
        DIY (Manual) decoration
        >>> print('Test with a function')
        Test with a function
        >>> def f(mylist): return math.prod(mylist)
        >>> Dec(chunk)(3).divide_and_run_DIY(f)(a)
        [6, 120, 504, 10]
        >>> # <function f at 0x7fa1fe6785e0>
        >>> print('Test with a method')
        Test with a method
        >>> class Dummy:
        ...     def multiply_all(self, mylist): return math.prod(mylist)
        >>> Dec(chunk)(3).divide_and_run_DIY(Dummy().multiply_all)(a)
        [6, 120, 504, 10]
        >>> # <bound method Dummy.multiply_all of <__main__.Dummy object at 0x7fa1fe6f7df0>>
        >>> print('='*20)
        ====================
        >>> print('SS decoration')
        SS decoration
        >>> print('Test with a function')
        Test with a function
        >>> @Dec(chunk)(3).divide_and_run_DIY
        ... def f(mylist): return math.prod(mylist)
        >>> f(a)
        [6, 120, 504, 10]
        >>> # <function f at 0x7fa1fe678940>
        >>> print('Test with a method')
        Test with a method
        >>> class Dummy:
        ...     @Dec(chunk)(3).divide_and_run_DIY
        ...     def multiply_all(self, mylist): return math.prod(mylist)
        >>> Dummy().multiply_all(a)
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        TypeError: object of type 'Dummy' has no len()
        >>> # <function Dummy.multiply_all at 0x7fa1fe678af0> # <-- it become a function!
        """
        if isinstance(f_target, types.MethodType):
            def wrapper(entries, *args, **kwargs):
                output = []
                for c in self.func(entries, *self.func_args, **self.func_kwargs):
                    output.append(f_target(c, *args, **kwargs))
                return output
        return wrapper

    def divide_and_run_SS(self, f_target):
        """Not universal solution, check the DANGER comments and remark 3.
        >>> print('Syntactic sugar decoration')
        Syntactic sugar decoration
        >>> print('function')
        function
        >>> @Dec(chunk)(3).divide_and_run_SS
        ... def f(mylist): return math.prod(mylist)
        >>> f(a)
        [6, 120, 504, 10]
        >>> # <function f at 0x7fd4de72d550>
        >>> print('instance method')
        instance method
        >>> class Dummy:
        ...     @Dec(chunk)(3).divide_and_run_SS
        ...     def multiply_all(self, mylist): return math.prod(mylist)
        >>> Dummy().multiply_all(a)
        [6, 120, 504, 10]
        >>> # <function Dummy.multiply_all at 0x7fd4de72da60>
        >>> print('='*20)
        ====================
        >>> print('SS (Manual) decoration')
        SS (Manual) decoration
        >>> print('function')
        function
        >>> def f(mylist): return math.prod(mylist)
        >>> Dec(chunk)(3).divide_and_run_SS(f)(a)
        [6, 120, 504, 10]
        >>> # <function f at 0x7f1221206550>
        >>> print('instance method')
        instance method
        >>> class Dummy:
        ...     def multiply_all(self, mylist): return math.prod(mylist)
        >>> Dec(chunk)(3).divide_and_run_SS(Dummy().multiply_all)(a)
        [6, 120, 504, 10]
        >>> # <bound method Dummy.multiply_all of <__main__.Dummy object at 0x7f1221284100>>
        """
        def wrapper(entries, *args, **kwargs):
            output = []
            # unnatural fix
            if len(args) > 0: # func <- "method" is a function due to @SS
                # reparametrization
                __self = entries    # <- DANGER
                __entries = args[0] # <- DANGER
                for c in self.func(__entries, *self.func_args, **self.func_kwargs):
                    output.append(f_target(__self, c, *args[1:], **kwargs))
            else: # func <- function
                for c in self.func(entries, *self.func_args, **self.func_kwargs):
                    output.append(f_target(c, *args, **kwargs))
            return output
        return wrapper
```

Check output with

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # run doctest
    doctest.testmod()

    # print __doc__
    print(Dec.divide_and_run_SS.__name__)
    print('#' * len(Dec.divide_and_run_SS.__name__))
    print(Dec.divide_and_run_SS.__doc__.replace('\t', ''))

    print(Dec.divide_and_run_DIY.__name__)
    print('#' * len(Dec.divide_and_run_DIY.__name__))
    print(Dec.divide_and_run_DIY.__doc__.replace('\t', ''))
```

---

EDIT:
`divide_and_run_SS_hack` is the re-implementation of `divide_and_run_SS`. It is **much more robust**, still lake of universality: it depends only on the identifier chosen to refer to the instance of a decorated method. Default is `'self'` string. It could (not tested yet + see answer of Blckknght + remark 1.) be made also compatible with class method, default `'cls'`, by adding a/some conditional branch/es and extending `vs[0] in {'self', 'cls'}`.

Here an example of a **failure**

```
class Dummy:
    @Dec(chunk)(3).divide_and_run_SS_hack
    def multiply_all(SELF, mylist): return math.prod(mylist) # capital case
```

**Part 1** + **Part2**: `divide_and_run_SS_hack`

```
class Dec:
    # ...

    def divide_and_run_SS_hack(self, f_target):
        """SS decoration hacky way. For method: assumed that in the implementation the "self" string is used to refer to  the object.
        >>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        >>> print('Syntactic sugar decoration - hacky way')
        Syntactic sugar decoration - hacky way
        >>> print('function')
        function
        >>> @Dec(chunk)(3).divide_and_run_SS_hack
        ... def f(mylist): return math.prod(mylist)
        >>> f(a)
        [6, 120, 504, 10]
        >>> print('instance method')
        instance method
        >>> class Dummy:
        ...     @Dec(chunk)(3).divide_and_run_SS_hack
        ...     def multiply_all(self, mylist): return math.prod(mylist)
        >>> Dummy().multiply_all(a)
        [6, 120, 504, 10]
        >>> print('='*20)
        ====================
        >>> print('SS (Manual) decoration')
        SS (Manual) decoration
        >>> print('function')
        function
        >>> def f(mylist): return math.prod(mylist)
        >>> Dec(chunk)(3).divide_and_run_SS_hack(f)(a)
        [6, 120, 504, 10]
        >>> print('instance method')
        instance method
        >>> class Dummy:
        ...     def multiply_all(self, mylist): return math.prod(mylist)
        >>> Dec(chunk)(3).divide_and_run_SS_hack(Dummy().multiply_all)(a)
        [6, 120, 504, 10]
        """
        vs = f_target.__code__.co_varnames
        if len(vs) > 0:
            # is method
            if vs[0] in {'self'}: # <- DANGER hardcoded
                # for @-decoration, method --> function
                if isinstance(f_target, types.FunctionType):
                    def wrapper(target_self, entries, *args, **kwargs): # <- "extra" parameter
                        output = []
                        for c in self.func(entries, *self.func_args, **self.func_kwargs):
                            output.append(f_target(target_self, c, *args, **kwargs)) # <- "extra" parameter
                        return output
                # for DIY-decoration
                elif isinstance(f_target, types.MethodType):
                    def wrapper(entries, *args, **kwargs):
                        output = []
                        for c in self.func(entries, *self.func_args, **self.func_kwargs):
                            output.append(f_target(c, *args, **kwargs))
                        return output
                return wrapper
        # is function
        def wrapper(entries, *args, **kwargs):
            output = []
            for c in self.func(entries, *self.func_args, **self.func_kwargs):
                output.append(f_target(c, *args, **kwargs))
            return output
        return wrapper
```

Comment: The `types.MethodType` type only works on bound methods, not methods at class definition time when the decorator gets applied. Hard coding a trigger on the name `"self"` would work, but it's very sketchy.